# Drawing on the iPhone using finger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I wish to provide the user with a panel(canvas), where he can draw his design which later is stored and later processed. While googling I have come across various approaches for drawing on the view
1.Using gestures
2.Using CGContext

I am confused on implementation of either methods. Which one of them would be better to use ? or Please suggest if there is any other better way to implement.Kindly share resources such as  code-snippets/demo project.

Comment: check this [apple Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit